# Get IProject from a custom IStorage implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently developing an Eclipse Neon editor plug-in. At the moment I'm trying to be able to open files from the filesystem, which weren't created inside of Eclipse. To accomplish that, I need to get an `IProject` in the following method:

```
public static IProject getProject(IStorage storage) {
    if (storage instanceof IFile) {
      return ((IFile) storage).getProject();
    }
    else if (storage instanceof IJarEntryResource) {
      return ((IJarEntryResource) storage).getPackageFragmentRoot().getJavaProject().getProject();
    }
    else if (storage instanceof FileStorage) {
      // ????
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown IStorage implementation");
    }
  }
```

Here `FileStorage` is an own implementation of the `IStorage` interface. And looks like that:

```
public class FileStorage implements IStorage {
  private final FileStoreEditorInput editorInput;

  FileStorage( FileStoreEditorInput editorInput ) {
    this.editorInput = editorInput;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T getAdapter( Class<T> adapter ) {
    return Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter( this, adapter );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isReadOnly() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return editorInput.getName();
  }

  @Override
  public IPath getFullPath() {
    return new Path( URIUtil.toFile( editorInput.getURI() ).getAbsolutePath() );
  }

  @Override
  public InputStream getContents() {
    try {
      return editorInput.getURI().toURL().openStream();
    } catch( IOException e ) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException( e );
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get an `IProject` from this `FileStorage`?

Comment: If the file isn't in a project you can't get an IProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and get an `IFile` for a file using:

```
IPath path = ... absolute path to the file

IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFile file = root.getFileForLocation(path);
if (file != null) {
  IProject project = file.getProject();
  ...
}
```

But this will only work for a file inside the workspace. For anything outside of the workspace you can't have a project.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No. The `FileStorage` class is meant to represent `IStorage` instances for files that are located **outside** of the workspace. Therefore they are not contained in any workspace project and it is not possible to obtain an `IProject` for them.